# on Hover set styling of DIV and P at the same time

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't quite work out how to do this, but I'm trying to set up my styling so on hover, it highlights seperate Elements at the same time.

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-4">
  <li>
    <img class="th" src="test.png"/>
       <p class="th1">Test Caption</p>
  </li>
</ul>

.th:hover, .th1:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(43, 166, 203, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(43, 166, 203, 0.5);
}
```

Is there a way to say on hover do this condition AND this other condition? because the above will do it for any item with the class that is hovered over but not all!

Comment: Are all the elements a child of what you're hovering?  e.g. `<th class="th">div1, div2</th>` and you want both divs to get an effect?

Comment: @EliGassert The elements are all nested but not set up as a child, I've added the html above if that helps you! What would you suggest looking at it?

Comment: Where are 'div1' and 'div2'?

Comment: @Switchfire then http://stackoverflow.com/a/19910401/1795053 this answer should get you what you need.  The other answer also does it with JS, but the answer I referenced is a pure CSS implementation.

Comment: @EliGassert So even if they are child elements of the on hover, you still have to write seperate statments for them with pure CSS?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "separate" rules.  I think your scoping is just off.  Now that you updated your markup, if you wanted both those elements to have a new style when you hover, then what you're actually hovering is the `li`, so `li:hover .th, li:hover .th1 { border: 2px solid red; }` now when you hover the li, both child elements will get a new border.

Comment: @EliGassert That's perfect, thanks Eli, well this shows me I've got to make sure I read up on my child elements and how they are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS trick would do the charm,

Apply a class to that `<li>` since it wraps the whole thing you want to apply. Then apply the `:hover` to the `<li>`'s class and then style the children.

HTML:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-4">
    <li class="wrapper">
        <img class="th" src="test.png" />
        <p class="th1">Test Caption</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper:hover .th, .wrapper:hover .th1{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(43, 166, 203, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(43, 166, 203, 0.5);
}
```

Working [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/V4cL9/)!

Answer (score 2):

If all elements are a child of the parent element you hover over, something like this:

```
.th:hover div1 { background: red; ... }
.th:hover div2 { background: tomato; ... }
```

At least, that's how I'm understanding the question.

Comment: So your still adding in a seperate statment for the other child elements?

Comment: He did this only to add a separate style.  If you needed them to have the SAME style, then you could combine it `.th:hover div1, .th:hover div2 { style }`

Comment: Here's a very simply example, if you uncomment out the first statement and remove the 2nd and 3rd statement, you'll see that become red. http://jsfiddle.net/uLMB7/

Answer (score 0):

If elements are children then look at the previous answer(s). If they aren't, could you do some JS. Here is simple example you could reuse:

http://jsfiddle.net/au89a/

```
<h1>My header</h1>
<div>My First Div</div>
<div>My second Div</div>


$("h1").mouseover(function() {
$("div").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(this).css("border","1px solid black"); // do whatever you want here
});
});

$("h1").mouseout(function() {
$("div").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(this).css("border",""); // do whatever you want here
});
});
```